# How to create an associate array through a loop (and retrieve its content through another)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, associative-array

After an hour googling around I'm utterly confused about how to create & manipulate an associative array (I know it's actually an object) in JS. I'm trying to build an associative array / object as I loop through my page's elements thus:

```
var array_modules = {};
$('.module').each(function() {
  var this_element = $(this);
  var module_top = this_element.data('top');
  var module_bottom = this_element.data('bottom');
  array_modules.push({'top': module_top, 'bottom': module_bottom});
});
```

And somewhere else I'd like to retrieve the content of my array thus:

```
for (var index in array_modules) {
  var top = array_modules['top'];
  var bottom = array_modules['bottom'];
  alert('top = ' + top + ' and bottom = ' + bottom);
}
```

None of this works though. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your first part of code you are using `array_modules` as just an array and not associative, just use `array_modules = [];` On second part you are iterating an associative array but it should be `array_modules[index]['top']`. Still, by just changing to array just make a `forEach` loop.

Anyway, this is what I would do :

```
var array_modules = [];

$('.module').each(function() {
  array_modules.push($(this).data());
});

array_modules.forEach(function(data){
    console.log(data.top, data.bottom);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

you can push data into an array only. I hope the below code works for you.

```
var array_modules = [];
$('.module').each(function() {
  var this_element = $(this);
  var module_top = this_element.data('top');
  var module_bottom = this_element.data('bottom');
  array_modules.push({'top': module_top, 'bottom': module_bottom});
});
for (var index in array_modules) {
  var top = array_modules[index]['top'];
  var bottom = array_modules[index]['bottom'];
  alert('top = ' + top + ' and bottom = ' + bottom);
}
```

This creates a array of associative objects

Comment: Thanks, right answer but @juvian gave it earlier so I had to validate his to be fair..